# Kernel - Starting the application

Tags: linux, boot, embedded

I placed the uBoot loader and the kernel into the raw flash image. This does not contain any root file system. (I copied uBoot and kernel image using dd command to a flash image).

Now i have to change my kernel as to start my application at a particular address which was located in my flash image.

How can I change the kernel to start my application on its own?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear.  Are you asking how to load an executable from the raw flash after the kernel has booted, or how to boot the kernel from the raw flash?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to need to have a filesystem on that flash, or else modify the kernel. You'll need to mount that as your root fs, and then pass the path to your program as a kernel parameter — `init=/bin/yourbinary`.

Comment: The problem is i don't have file system in my flash. I have to invoke the application directly from the kernel

Comment: Unless you are trying to execute your application from the flash (ie, not copy it into ram) it may be simplest to use a file system rather than try to figure out how to go without.  If you are planning to execute from flash, realize this will be substantially slower than ram unless you can stay in the processor cache almost all of the time.